# How can I read a binary file into a protobuf that is of the type QString?

Tags: c++, qt, file, protocol-buffers

So I have a binary file and its name is being passed into my function as `const QString& filename` and I'm trying to read it into a ProtoBuf. I have tried the example `ParseFromArray(file.data(), file.size())` but it doesn't work and has size `1`.

What is the correct way to do this? Thank you!

Here's my relevant code snippet:

```
bool open(const QString& filename)
{
    myProject::protobuf::Example _example;

    // need to copy contents from file to _example
}
```

Comment: Is `file` the file _name_ or the file _contents_?

Comment: Please show your relevant code. Looks like you need to read all first using `QFile` and then get the `data` from the returned `QByteArray`. But, that would be speculative. You'd get better responses once you updated your code.

Comment: ```file``` is the name of the file

Comment: I have updated the code please let me know if there is anything else I need to provide. Thanks!

Comment: @Kau: I've updated your question as per your previous comment that `file` is the `filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file first using [`QFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) and then read its contents using its inherited method [`readAll()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) which will return a [`QByteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html). Then, use [`QByteArray::data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data-1) and [`QByteArray::size()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#size) to pass to `ParseFromArray(const void* data, int size)`. You also need to take care of the error-handling wherever required.

Here's an example:

```
bool open( const QString& filename )
{
    QFile file { filename };
    if ( !file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) ) return false;

    const auto data = file.readAll();
    if ( data.isEmpty() ) return false;

    if ( !ParseFromArray( data.data(), data.size() ) ) return false;

    // successful parsing: process here...

    return true;
}
```